# typeorm: how do I correctly save a lazy related entity with {nullable: false}?

Tags: lazy-loading, typeorm, non-nullable, node.js-typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

**Stack:**

- Typeorm: 0.3.15
- Node
- Express: ^4.18.2
- Typescript
- MySQL

I have a `User` entity in my application that has a reference property to its parent `Organization`. I've mapped the organization property as a Promise to enforce lazy loading and its reference column, `oid`, is also mapped using `{ nullable: false }` to ensure that the organization is set on a user before that user can be saved to the database:

**User:**

```
    @Entity('users')
    export class User extends IdentifiableEntity implements OrganizationalEntity {
      
      ...
    
      @ManyToOne(() => Organization, org => org.users, {
        nullable: false,
      })
      @JoinColumn({name: 'oid'})
      org: Promise<Organization>;
    
      ...
    
    }
```

**Organization:**

```
    @Entity('organizations')
    export class Organization extends IdentifiableEntity {
      
      ...
    
      @OneToMany(() => User, user => user.org)
      users: Promise<User[]>;
    
      ...
    
    }
```

When I set the organization prior to calling save on the User repository, I'm setting it using: `user.org = Promise.resolve(new Organization(oid))` as indicated in the [typeorm documentation for lazy references](https://typeorm.io/eager-and-lazy-relations) and shown in the documentation on [how to save a lazy relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iexXE.png).

Unfortunately, the save fails with the following MySQL database error:

```
    QueryFailedError: Field 'oid' doesn't have a default value
        at Query.onResult (/Users/me/workspace/api/src/driver/mysql/MysqlQueryRunner.ts:222:33)
        at Query.execute (/Users/me/workspace/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:36:14)
        at PoolConnection.handlePacket (/Users/me/workspace/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:489:32)
        at PacketParser.onPacket (/Users/me/workspace/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:94:12)
        at PacketParser.executeStart (/Users/me/workspace/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/me/workspace/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:101:25)
        at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
        at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
        at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
        at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9) {
      query: 'INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `deletedAt`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `department`, `position`, `startDate`, `emails`, `oid`) VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, DEFAULT)',
      parameters: [
        'New',
        'User',
        'Marketing',
        'Head of Marketing',
        2023-05-04T07:42:18.000Z,
        '["me2@my.email"]'
      ],
      driverError: Error: Field 'oid' doesn't have a default value
```

If I remove the `{ nullable: false }` constraint from the `org` property on the `User` entity, the user is saved in the database but the `oid` property is never set, leaving a `null` value for `oid` in the `User` row.

**Has anyone else ran into this and, if so, what's the best way to resolve this error?**

I have found a few posts in other online forums that have suggested defining the relation as:

**User:**

```
    @Entity('users')
    export class User extends IdentifiableEntity implements OrganizationalEntity {
      
      ...
    
      @ManyToOne(() => Organization, org => org.users, {
        nullable: false,
      })
      @JoinColumn({name: 'oid'})
      org: Promise<Organization> | Organization;
    
      ...
    
    }
```

and setting the property using `user.org = new Organization(oid)`, without the `Promise`. This does work, however, I didn't find anything on the [Typeorm website](https://typeorm.io/) that indicates this is a correct solution. I'm also unsure how having both `Promise<Organization>` and `Organization` as types for the `User.org` property will affect lazy loading of that entity. e.g. will it still be lazy because *one* of the options is a Promise?

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem
as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69007576/16676419) I changed object type in entity to `Promise<T>` and tried to fill them with `Promise.resolve()` but it didn't fill column and because that field couldn't be nullable I got error.
I rolled back that field from `Promise<T>` to `T` and as I tested everything seems ok, I didn't test if query will get lazy object or not so don't know if didn't using Promise bypassed `lazy` functionality (don't know if it's related to that or not)

ps. according to [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/vx26sy/comment/ifu1y21/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) that led to [this release todo by typeorm creator (pleerock)](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3251#issue-390989433) it seems `lazy` and `eager` are not ideal and he tries to deprecate them.

here's more [description by pleerock](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/2966#issuecomment-433618915)

**EDIT:**
i found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59322884/typeorm-does-not-save-relations) today and it seems related. I didn't test it yet but it seems we need to use cascade for this to work.